# how to refer timestamp variable in pgsql function having select statement

Tags: postgresql, sql-timestamp

Hi Am trying to write a pgsql function which performs copy of table data to a csv file and am having difficulty using the variable value inside the function as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION test3() RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
DECLARE
_currenttime timestamp := now();
BEGIN
copy (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE createdtime < _currenttime - INTERVAL '1 days') TO '/tmp/table1.csv';
END
$$;
```

I get error while accessing the function:

```
select test3();
```

> ERROR:  column "_currenttime" does not exist LINE 1: ...py (SELECT *
>   FROM table1 WHERE createdtime < _currentti...
>                                                                ^ QUERY:  copy (SELECT * FROM bpminstance WHERE createdtime < _currenttime -
>   INTERVAL '1 days') TO '/tmp/table1.csv'

Request your kind help.

Comment: in the error output bpminstance  refers to table1

Comment: try `copy (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE createdtime < NOW() - interval '1 day') TO '/tmp/table1.csv';`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but i have other statements followed by this, so i need to refer this variable across the script.

Comment: I have series of copy commands and based on the current time stamp which i store in the variable i need to collect data. so that all tables give data based on that variable.

And i tried your suggestion and got the error:
\i /home/cust/test3.sql
psql:/home/cust/createFunction_3.sql:69: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":="
LINE 15: ...FROM table1 WHERE createdtime < _currenttime := NOW() -...

Am new to adding post to stackoverflow, just getting to know things, forgive for the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION test3() RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
 DECLARE
_currenttime timestamp;
qry text;
BEGIN
_currenttime := NOW() - interval '1 day';
select 'copy (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE createdtime < '''||_currenttime||''') TO ''/tmp/table1.csv''' into qry;
execute qry;
--codes
END
$$;
```

Comment: I tried this, no error on executing function but there was no data copied to csv file, any idea ? But if i execute that command separately i get result

Comment: **Ok using < _currenttime, get the following error**:

 select test3();
NOTICE:  current time for archiving is 2015-10-11 18:01:17.461973
ERROR:  column "_currenttime" does not exist
LINE 1: ...py (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE createdtime < _currentti...
                                                             ^
QUERY:  copy (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE createdtime < _currenttime) TO '/tmp/table1.csv'
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test3() line 8 at SQL statement

Comment: **Using '||_currenttime||'** 
select test3();
NOTICE:  current time for archiving is 2015-10-11 17:59:51.982964
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "||_currenttime||"
LINE 1: ...py (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE createdtime < '||_curren...
                                                             ^
QUERY:  copy (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE createdtime < '||_currenttime||') TO '/tmp/table1.csv'
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test3() line 8 at SQL statement

Comment: The variable seems to be resolving but with some errors as below:

 select test3();
NOTICE:  current time for archiving is 2015-10-11 19:10:37.398026
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "19"
LINE 1: ...* FROM table1 WHERE createdtime < 2015-10-11 19:10:37.3...
                                                             ^
QUERY:  copy (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE createdtime < 2015-10-11 19:10:37.398026) TO '/tmp/table1.csv'
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test3() line 10 at EXECUTE statement